# Rails 4: Own engine "No route matches"

Tags: ruby, routes, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4

I write..

```
rails new testapp
cd testapp/
rails plugin new blog --mountable
cd blog/
rails g scaffold post name description:text
rake db:migrate
cd ../
rails s
```

Go to localhost:3000/blog/posts/index and i get error "No route matches [GET] "/blog/posts/index""

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the engine at some random directory inside your application won't make it magically work. I don't know where you learned this technique from, but it is wrong.

You should put the engine outside your application and require it into your application's Gemfile, like this:

```
gem 'blog', :path => '../blog'
```

Then the engine will be automatically loaded by Rails.

The [Engines Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) goes into more detail. I highly recommend reading that.